# Фильтр для ListView из CheckBox

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

В активности присутствует ListView с CheckBox-ами, часть из которых отмечена, также есть EditText для фильтрации списка по буквам.

> MainActivity.java

```
package ru.test.listview_checkbox_getfilter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listViewCgoicePair;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListPair = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListVisiblePair = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterChocePair;
    private EditText filterText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayListPair.add("11");
        arrayListPair.add("12");
        arrayListPair.add("13");
        arrayListPair.add("21");
        arrayListPair.add("22");
        arrayListPair.add("23");

        arrayListVisiblePair.add("11");
        arrayListVisiblePair.add("12");
        arrayListVisiblePair.add("23");

        listViewCgoicePair = findViewById(R.id.listViewChoicePair);
        listViewCgoicePair.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        adapterChocePair = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arrayListPair);

        listViewCgoicePair.setAdapter(adapterChocePair);
        for (String checkedPair:arrayListVisiblePair){
            listViewCgoicePair.setItemChecked(arrayListPair.indexOf(checkedPair), true);
        }
        filterText = findViewById(R.id.editTextChicePair);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapterChocePair.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextChicePair"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewChoicePair"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Проблема состоит в том, что когда применяется фильтр, не подходящие значения удаляются, но отмеченные CheckBox-ы остаются на своих местах и уже соответствуют другим записям. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такой же вопрос с [ответом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731983/android-change-checkbox-checked-value-in-listview-when-getfilter-called).
Но разобраться до конца не смог, по этому решил изобрести велосипед и написал свой метод фильтрации. Пишите критику, буду рад, учусь.

> MainActivity.java

```
package ru.test.listview_checkbox_getfilter;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listViewCgoicePair;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListPair = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> arrayListVisiblePair = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterChocePair;
    private EditText filterText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        arrayListPair.add("Ab");
        arrayListPair.add("ab");
        arrayListPair.add("aB");
        arrayListPair.add("bA");
        arrayListPair.add("ba");
        arrayListPair.add("Ba");

        arrayListVisiblePair.add("Ab");
        arrayListVisiblePair.add("ab");
        arrayListVisiblePair.add("Ba");

        listViewCgoicePair = findViewById(R.id.listViewChoicePair);
        listViewCgoicePair.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        adapterChocePair = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arrayListPair);

        listViewCgoicePair.setAdapter(adapterChocePair);
        updateCheckedBox(arrayListPair);

        filterText = findViewById(R.id.editTextChicePair);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void filter(CharSequence s) {
        ArrayList<String> arrayPair = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String pair : arrayListPair) {
            if (pair.toLowerCase().contains(s.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                arrayPair.add(pair);
            }
        }
        adapterChocePair = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, arrayPair);
        listViewCgoicePair.setAdapter(adapterChocePair);
        updateCheckedBox(arrayPair);
    }

    private void updateCheckedBox(ArrayList<String> arrayCheckBox) {
        for (String checkedPair : arrayListVisiblePair) {
            listViewCgoicePair.setItemChecked(arrayCheckBox.indexOf(checkedPair), true);
        }
    }
}
```